# What does $c+i\infty$ means

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, notation

I found this integral on a page but I'm wondering what's its meaning :
$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{u^{-z} \Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(1+m+z)}dz$$
where $c>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$
What's the meaning of $c+i\infty$ ? And does this integral have a solution ?
(I'm a 12th grade student)

Comment: You can think of it as the vertical line $x =c $.

Comment: Imagine just choosing a real number $c$ sitting in the complex plane. Then, integrating from $c - i\infty$ to $c + i\infty$ is basically integrating over the vertical line passing through $c$.

Comment: What page were you reading? It's interesting that you are aware of the Gamma function , which is in the integrand, in 12th grade.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon it's an account on twitter and yes I knew this marvelous function since I was in 10th grade, but never could use it to solve actual problems like this one...

Comment: Integrals like this (emphasis on *like*, not exactly the same) pop up frequently with Perron’s formula. You might look into that for some tips (and for a reference, Davenport’s *Multiplicative Number Theory* covers it in some detail).

Comment: I add two links for the notation $c+i\infty$: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40819-015-0057-3, https://academic.oup.com/imatrm/article/3/1/tnz006/5567391.